# Angular dynamic form with variable content

Tags: angular, forms

I need to present a set of questions fetched from an API, and having trouble displaying the form in the template, and getting the correct values of the user's response. 
The format of the APIs response is the following:

```
{
  questions: [
  {
    text: 'Is this a question?',
    id: 'question1',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Yes', id: 'answer1' },
      { text: 'No!', id: 'answer2' },
      { text: 'Don't know?', id: 'answer3' }
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

I have created a form which looks like the following:

**In the component**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.questionsAnswersForm = this.fb.group({
      answers: this.fb.array([])
    }); 
  }
this.initFormWithQAs()
```

```
initFormWithQAs(): void {
  this.questions.map(() =>
    (<FormArray>this.questionsAnswersForm.get('answers')).push(
      this.addQuestionFormGroup()
    )
  );
}
```

```
 addQuestionFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      questionId: [null, Validators.required],
      answerId: [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

**In the template**

```
<div formArrayName="answers" *ngFor="let q of questions">
    <h5>{{ q.text }}</h5>
      <form  [formGroupName]="q.id" class="qa-list">
        <label *ngFor="let answer of q.answers">
          <input
            type="radio"
            [value]="answer.id"
            [formControlName]="answer.id"
          />
         <span>{{ answer.text }}</span>
       </label>
     </form>
  </div>
```

The questionnaire renders on the screen with the correct text, but the radio buttons are not uniquely selected (working like checkboxes), the values on form submit are always null, and i am  also getting the following error:

> > TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'question1'

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just built something for you to generate dynamic reactive form based on data from api

this is .ts file file

```
  questions = [
    {
      text: 'Is this a question?',
      id: 'question1',
      answers: [
        { text: 'Yes', id: 'answer1' },
        { text: 'No!', id: 'answer2' },
        { text: 'Dont know?', id: 'answer3' }
      ]
    }
  ]


  questionsAnswersForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.questionsAnswersForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.initFormWithQAs();
  }

  initFormWithQAs(): void {
    this.questions.forEach((question) => {
      const questionAnswersGroup = this.fb.group({});
      question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        questionAnswersGroup.addControl(answer.id, new FormControl(false));
      });
      this.questionsAnswersForm.addControl(question.id, questionAnswersGroup);
    });
  }

  display() {
    console.log(this.questionsAnswersForm.value);

  }
```

// To add required custom validation

```
initFormWithQAs(): void {
    this.questions.forEach((question) => {
      const questionAnswersGroup = this.fb.group({});
      questionAnswersGroup
        .setValidators([function (control) {
          if (!Object.values(control.value).reduce((a, b) => a || b)) {
            return { required: true };
          }
          return null
        }]);
      question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        questionAnswersGroup.addControl(answer.id, new FormControl(false));
      });
      this.questionsAnswersForm.addControl(question.id, questionAnswersGroup);
    });
  }
```

and this is the html template

```
<form [formGroup]="questionsAnswersForm">
    <div [formGroupName]="q.id" *ngFor="let q of questions">
        <h5>{{ q.text }}</h5>
        <label *ngFor="let answer of q.answers">
            <input type="radio" [value]="answer.id" [formControlName]="answer.id" />
            <span>{{ answer.text }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button (click)="display()">Display values</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is definitely a huge step forward!! How would I make the form invalid until all questions have been answered? Adding a `Validators.required` in the FormControl doesnt do the trick :/

Comment: @GeorgeK I added custom validation to the answer